# Ruby on Rails rake db:seed undefined in rails tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following this tutorial https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users#top and am at step 12.14. I've followed each step except the ones adding test data because I'm using this tutorial to help me learn to develop a follower following feature on my own project.

Here is the error message from my console:

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
/Users/alexanderkehaya/Desktop/wewrite/db/seeds.rb:13:in
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong/missing? **Edit: How do I get the seed data to rake successfully?**

Thanks for the help.

Here is my data:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20141030023857) do

create_table "collaborators_stories", id: false, force: true do |t|
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.integer  "collaborator_id"
t.integer  "story_id"
end

create_table "lines", force: true do |t|
t.string   "text"
t.integer  "score",            default: 0
t.integer  "depth",            default: 0
t.integer  "previous_line_id"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.integer  "user_id"
t.integer  "story_id"
end

create_table "relationships", force: true do |t|
t.integer  "follower_id"
t.integer  "followed_id"
t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
end

add_index "relationships", ["followed_id"], name: "index_relationships_on_followed_id"
add_index "relationships", ["follower_id", "followed_id"], name:      "index_relationships_on_follower_id_and_followed_id", unique: true
add_index "relationships", ["follower_id"], name: "index_relationships_on_follower_id"

create_table "stories", force: true do |t|
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "users", force: true do |t|
t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
t.string   "reset_password_token"
t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
t.datetime "remember_created_at"
t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.string   "provider"
t.string   "uid"
t.string   "name"
t.string   "profile_image_url"
end

add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique:   true

end
```

Here is my user.rb file:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :omniauthable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

has_many :lines
has_many :active_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                              foreign_key: "follower_id",
                              dependent:   :destroy
has_many :passive_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                              foreign_key: "followed_id",
                              dependent:   :destroy
has_many :following, through: :active_relationships, source: :followed
has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower
has_and_belongs_to_many :stories, :foreign_key => :collaborator_id, :join_table => :collaborators_stories

def profile_image_uri(size = "mini")
    # parse_encoded_uri(insecure_uri(profile_image_uri_https(size))) unless @attrs[:profile_image_url_https].nil?
    unless self.provider == "facebook"
        self.profile_image_url.sub! "normal", size  unless self.profile_image_url.nil?
    else
        self.profile_image_url
    end
end

#Follows a user.
def follow(other_user)
    active_relationships.create(followed_id: other_user.id)
end

 # Unfollows a user.
def unfollow(other_user)
    active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: other_user.id).destroy
end

 # Returns true if the current user is following the other user.
def following?(other_user)
    following.include?(other_user)
end
def self.find_for_twitter_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)


    user = User.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first

    if user

      if user.profile_image_url != auth.extra.raw_info.profile_image_url 
         user.update_attribute(:profile_image_url, auth.extra.raw_info.profile_image_url)
      end

      return user 

    else
      registered_user = User.where(:email => auth.uid + "@twitter.com").first

      if registered_user

        return registered_user
      else

        user = User.create(name:auth.extra.raw_info.name,
                            provider:auth.provider, 
                            profile_image_url:auth.extra.raw_info.profile_image_url,
                            uid:auth.uid,
                            email:auth.uid+"@twitter.com",
                            password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20],
                          )
      end
    end 
  end

  def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)

    user = User.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
    if user

        if user.profile_image_url != auth.info.image 
         user.update_attribute(:profile_image_url, auth.info.image)
      end

      return user
    else
      registered_user = User.where(:email => auth.info.email).first
      if registered_user
        return registered_user
      else
        user = User.create(name:auth.extra.raw_info.name,
                            provider:auth.provider, 
                            profile_image_url:auth.info.image,
                            uid:auth.uid,
                            email:auth.info.email,
                            password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20],
                          )
  end   
 end
end
end
```

Here is my relationships.rb file:

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
 belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"
 validates :follower_id, presence: true
 validates :followed_id, presence: true
end
```

EDIT: I added my seeds file:

```
users = User.all
user  = users.first
following = users[2..50]
followers = users[3..40]
following.each { |followed| user.follow(followed) }
followers.each { |follower| follower.follow(user) }
```

Comment: What is your question

Comment: Just added an edit at the top. Question is: How do I get rid of the error? I'm new to rails/coding in general. Not sure where to look for the problem. @anusha

Comment: the error is because you don't have any records in `following` once remove that from seed file and try and check whether `user` table get the records in it or not

Comment: How many record you have in your user table. It clearly indicate you only have one record in your user table. Have you added `    99.times do |n|
      name  = Faker::Name.name
      email = "example-#{n+1}@railstutorial.org"
      password = "password"
      User.create!(name: name,
                  email: email,
                  password:              password,
                  password_confirmation: password,
                  activated: true,
                  activated_at: Time.zone.now)
    end` block in seed file. If not add it in seed file and all is good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message explains itself. `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass` tells you that you are tryiing to send `each` method to a `nil` object. It can be deduced that `following` and/or `followers`, on which you are calling `each`, are `nil`, not an `ActiveRecord Relation` object you hope it to be.

Did you remember to create User objects in your seed file? If your seed file is just as shown in your question, it wouldn't work because `User` model does not have any objects in it.

You must create them first as shown in [here](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users#code-sample_relationships) listing 12.14. You can either use FactoryGirl like Railstutorial does, or just plain Ruby.

Comment: @user3787971 If you want to use FactoryGirl, add it to your application. The bottom line is you have to generate and persist some records to User before those code can work.

Comment: Thanks @MikeC that was the right direction. I figured it out and learned a lot.